# How to hold reference to different forms with one variable

Tags: vb.net, winforms

- I have a Form (named Form1) which has a fixed size and some controls.
- I created another Form (named Form2), which is a copy of Form1 with only difference being a different fixed size.
- I created a Form "SharedForm", which holds subs and functions used by both forms (so I don't have to write them for each of them).

*My problem is:* I don't know how to keep reference for either form (only one at a time, ever).

If I declare FormRef variable as Form, I get an error that "label1 is not a member of form".
(Otherwise if I declare as Form1 or Form2 it works fine, but of course only for one form)

---

SharedForm looks like the following:

[image]

```
Public Class SharedForm

    Public Shared FormRef As Form 'problem is here

    Private Sub SharedForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FormRef = New Form2
        FormRef.Show()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        FormRef.Label1.Text = "test"
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

Form1 and Form2 are as so.

[image] [image]

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf SharedForm.Button1_Click
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf SharedForm.Button1_Click
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It is not obvious why you created a new Form class when Form1 can do the job of both.  The 2nd instance only needs a different Size value.

Comment: @HansPassant It is because it's easier to deal with design wise, it's not a standard form but a complex shape, buttons are even "crafted" individually. It's easier to set up everything where it should be and animations with another form.

Comment: @CruleD How do you feel about using `Option Strict Off` ? If you are okay with it, you can simply declare the `FormRef` as `Object`.

Comment: @JayV I would like to keep it now. I'm looking into some kind of dynamic type declaration, would that work?

Comment: Is `SharedForm` a base `Form` class shared by the other two forms, or just a helper class, with an instance contained by each of the other two forms? Either way, it seems like that would be the natural place to share the functionality in the two forms. Fact is, if it's not the shared based class, it probably should be, then `Label1` can be in that class, and your `FormRef` can be declared as that type. Unfortunately, your question lacks a [mcve] and so is too vague to actually answer.

Comment: @JayV - Please never suggest `Option Strict Off`. You might as well say `Run With Scissors`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I changed the "sharedform" one to actual form now and put all the code so anyone can replicate. Can you try to answer now? Could you explain it simpler maybe, I'm not quite familiar with the terminology (differences between those).

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977200/sharing-code-between-derived-forms. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvb.net%5D+%5Bwinforms%5D+inherit+form. The Winforms Designer doesn't always work gracefully with inherited form classes, so it may require some fiddling to get it to work right. For example, you might have to hand-edit the Designer file to change the base class of your derived forms (the Designer will just make the base class `Form`, not `SharedForm`).

Comment: @PeterDuniho All 3 are Form(s). There's no extra inheritance here.

Comment: Then you've missed the point. `SharedForm` should inherit `Form`, and the other two forms classes should inherit `SharedForm`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho That means `SharedForm` should have all the controls right? Since atm Form1 has the controls, Form2 is supposed to just be a bigger sized form1, and `SharedForm` was supposed to share methods between the two so I don't have to duplicate the code.

Comment: _"That means SharedForm should have all the controls right?"_ -- yes. Frankly, I question the choice to subclass the form solely for the purpose of having different sizes, but if you insist, then at least put everything not related to layout in the shared base class.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Hmm, having 3 copies of the current `form1`'s design doesn't seem that much more efficient than 2 independent ones. Is there any other way I could handle two forms with something one the side that shares the code between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a class, not a Form.

```
Public Class EventCode
    Public Shared Sub Button1Click(Sender As Form)
        Dim frm As Form = Nothing
        If Sender.Name = "Form1" Then
            frm = DirectCast(Sender, Form1)
        ElseIf Sender.Name = "Form2" Then
            frm = DirectCast(Sender, Form2)
        End If
        frm.Controls("Label1").Text = "Hello World"
    End Sub
End Class
```

In Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    EventCode.Button1Click(Me)
End Sub
```

The label on Form1 shows "Hello World"

In Form2

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    EventCode.Button1Click(Me)
End Sub
```

The label on Form2 shows "Hello World"

Comment: Thanks Mary, I managed to do it before seeing this though. After dealing with some MS bugs I ended up with: Form1 that inherits Form, Form2 that Inherits Form1 and a SharedForm that inherits Form. Form2 uses the code from Form1 without witting anything for it, while some extras are handled in SharedForm.